# AC delay circuit question

Tags: ac, delay

Sorry if it's a stupid question but.. is there any AC delay circuit? All I know is RC and RL circuits but are based on DC current
For example, to delay for a second the triggering of an AC relay
thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What do you actually mean by AC delay? Intentional phase delay between an input and an output, or between voltage and current? Or something else? Maybe you can give more info about the possible application and/or purpose.

Comment: @jmann you also need to state if you require a frequency independent delay or you need only a delay at a particular fixed AC frequency ? Elaborate ...

Comment: sorry, I added an example.. only time delay with fixed AC frequency

Comment: You can use the same RC circuit, just use a rectified voltage to supply it. The load of course can stay AC supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are AC time-delay relays, usually based on heating a bimetallic strip at a controlled rate.

Other methods for more complex sequencing include motor-driven cam switches, etc.

I can't think of any purely electronic methods that don't involve converting the AC to DC at some point.